# Update Entity with Live Data in Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to show an entity moving within Cesium using live/dynamic data. I have tried multiple techniques from reading from earlier forums, mostly from 2015-2016. I just would like to know how to get it to work.

This is what I have currently. I have tried every method I have found on stackoverflow and Cesium forums and every time nothing will even load. It's a blank screen every time.

```
Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = 'xxxx';

const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
  terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain()
});
    
const osmBuildings = viewer.scene.primitives.add(Cesium.createOsmBuildings());

const data = JSON.parse('C:/Users/moose/Documents/Cesium/telemetryGet.json');

var telemetry = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(data.longitude, data.latitude, data.altitude);
var dronePositions = new Cesium.SampledPositionProperty();
dronePositions.addSample( Cesium.JulianDate.fromDate(new Date()), telemetry);
// Load the glTF model from Cesium ion.
const airplaneUri = await Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(1634734);
const DroneEntity = viewer.entities.add({
  position: dronePositions,
  // Attach the 3D model instead of the green point.
  model: { uri: airplaneUri },
  // Automatically compute the orientation from the position.
  orientation: new Cesium.VelocityOrientationProperty(telemetry),    
});

viewer.selectedEntity = DroneEntity;

  // setTimeout(loadModel, 1000);

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);

var clock = viewer.clock;
var lastUpdated = clock.currentTime;
clock.onTick.addEventListener(function() {
    var dt = Cesium.JulianDate.secondsDifference(clock.currentTime, lastUpdated);
    if (dt >= 1.0) {
        // Add a new sample position
        lastUpdated = clock.currentTime;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that problem is in dronePositions.addSample.
addSample 's first parameter, time should drop in the time range of the clock of your viewer.

Here's the working code.

[Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

```
const {
    BoundingSphere,
    Cartesian3,
    ClockRange,
    JulianDate,
    SampledPositionProperty,
    VelocityOrientationProperty,
    Viewer
} = window.Cesium;

const viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
    shouldAnimate: true
});

const startTime = JulianDate.fromDate(new Date(2019, 5, 10, 13));
const stopTime = JulianDate.addSeconds(startTime, 10, new JulianDate());

viewer.clock.startTime = startTime.clone();
viewer.clock.stopTime = stopTime.clone();
viewer.clock.shouldAnimate = true;
viewer.clock.clockRange = ClockRange.LOOP_STOP;

viewer.timeline.zoomTo(startTime, stopTime);

const latitude = 38;
const longitude = 127;
const altitude = 10;

const dronePositions = new SampledPositionProperty();

const startPoint = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude, altitude);

dronePositions.addSample(startTime, startPoint);

const endPoint = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude + 0.001, latitude, altitude);

dronePositions.addSample(stopTime, endPoint);

const airplaneUri = "../SampleData/models/CesiumDrone/CesiumDrone.glb";

const DroneEntity = viewer.entities.add({
    position: dronePositions,

    // Attach the 3D model instead of the green point.
    model: { uri: airplaneUri },
    // Automatically compute the orientation from the position.
    orientation: new VelocityOrientationProperty(dronePositions)
});

viewer.camera.flyToBoundingSphere(BoundingSphere.fromPoints([startPoint, endPoint]));
```